# Issue while connecting gremlin and gephi

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to connect gremlin which is on remote server with gephi. The gremlin uses the backend as cassandra in Titan-1.0.0. And also I have configured to connect to the server

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-objects.yaml
==>Connected - ip-10-125-10-127.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.125.10.127:8182
```

But when is execute this,

```
:> g
```

I get the following error:

```
10:13:41 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer  - Response [PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 136, widx: 136, cap: 136)] could not be deserialized by     org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0.
10:13:41 ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler  - Could not process the response - correct the problem and restart the driver.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 121, Size: 0
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler.channelRead0(WebSocketClientHandler.java:90)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:182)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 121, Size: 0
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0.deserializeResponse(GryoMessageSerializerV1d0.java:216)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:49)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:36)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 121, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.util.MapReferenceResolver.getReadObject(MapReferenceResolver.java:60)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readReferenceOrNull(Kryo.java:831)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:725)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0.deserializeResponse(GryoMessageSerializerV1d0.java:199)
    ... 23 more
Index: 121, Size: 0
```

And in the webconsole 10.125.10.127:8182 with the port opened, i get

```
not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade
```

Comment: I edited the gremlin-server.yaml file, changed the channelizer to **channelizer:com.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer** now i get this error,`WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler  - Exception caught during WebSocket processing - closing connection
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 400 Bad Request....
ERRORorg.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler - Could not process the response-correct the problem and restart the driver`which runs indefinitely

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do. The title of your question asks about gephi but what does gephi have to do with your question? This looks like you just want to connect the Gremlin Console to Gremlin Server hosting a Titan database, no?

Comment: yes!!! i want to send the graph from the gremlin to gephi. So while doing :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-objects.yaml i get that error. But this time i get the {"message":"no gremlin script supplied"} in my webconsole which is correct.But the error runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up some things. If your primary requirement is to connect to Titan to visualize a graph in Gephi then the easiest way to do that is to just open a `TitanGraph` instance in the Titan Gremlin Console

```
graph = TitanFactory.open(...)
```

and then follow the instructions here:

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#gephi-plugin

You don't want to connect with a `:remote` to Gremlin Server as you need a local `Graph` instance to work with Gephi. Note that `:remote` does not connect to the `HttpChannelizer` - that is for REST base communication and `:remote` works over websockets which requires the `WebSocketChannelizer`.